# Composer - specify `composer.json` path

Tags: php, dependencies, composer-php

Is it possible to specify the path to the `composer.json` file using the cli commands? Even better, is it possible to user a file with a different name?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I would suggest you take a look at this:
https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#environment-variables

> **COMPOSER**
>
> By setting the `COMPOSER` env variable it is possible to set the filename of `composer.json` to something else.
>
> For example:
>
> `COMPOSER=composer-other.json php composer.phar install`
>
> The generated lock file will use the same name: `composer-other.lock` in this example.

Comment: what's the windows syntax? using your example command give me  `Command "=composer-other.json" is not defined.`

Comment: @realtebo Can you try this using GIT Bash for Windows? I don't think the default windows command line supports export variables.

Comment: @realtebo
Windows version of this command would be `set COMPOSER=composer-other.json php composer.phar install`

But i see the documentation has an error, the value mus be only the file, so the correct command would be `set COMPOSER=composer-other.json`

Comment: to truly answer the question ho to specify the path, you should know that you can add a path in COMPOSER-variable to, but you need to specify the vendor dir to, if you try to run a composer install in a sub-directory e.g. like this:

`COMPOSER=subdir\composer-other.json &&  COMPOSER_VENDOR_DIR=subdir\vendor`